# in ng-show not working while clicking reply link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

```html
<html lang="en" ng-app=“myDiscuss">
<head><!-- all the script files-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="thumbnail" ng-controller="TabController as tabs”>

<!-- some other div-->

        <div ng-show="tabs.isSelected(1)">
                    <small>No of likes</small>
        </div>



            <section class="caption"  >

                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">

                            <li ng-class="{ active:tab === 1 }" >
                                <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(1)">Helpful</a>
                            </li>
                            <li ng-class= "{ active:tab === 2 }">
                                <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(2)">Comment</a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="panel" ng-show="tabs.isSelected(2)">

                            <blockquote>
                                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                    <li ng-class="{ active:tab === 3 }" >
                                        <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(3)" >Helpful</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li ng-class= "{ active:tab === 4}">
                                        <a href ng-click="tabs.selectTab(4)">Reply</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <input type="text" ng-show="tabs.isSelected(4)">
                            </blockquote>
                    </div>
            </section>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
JavaScript File

var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", []);

app.controller("TabController", function() {
    this.tab=0;
    this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        this.tab= setTab;
    };
    this.isSelected = (function(checkTab){
        return this.tab === checkTab;
    });
});
```

When I click the "Comment" Link it open the div "panel". whereas when i click "Reply" link it doesn't open input tag.

[Image with comment and helpful link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgwTY.png) 
[The div "panel" which open when comment link is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOmZW.png)

Comment: Where your function `selectTab` invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it's working but since you are using same this.tab variable it's not working. You should take separate variable.

Take separate variable for main tabs & sub tabs or you can use another method to separate main tabs & sub tabs. Like 1.1 or 3.3 etc. There are many ways.

```
this.tab=0;
this.subTab = 0;
this.selectTab = function(setTab) {
    this.tab= setTab;
};
this.selectSubTab = function(setTab){
    this.subTab = setTab;
};
this.isSelected = (function(checkTab){
    return this.tab === checkTab;
});
 this.isSelectedSub = (function(checkTab){
    return this.subTab === checkTab;
});
```

check the https://plnkr.co/edit/leTBpJUVC7giDCs9KtQX

Comment: Isn't this a bit redundant?

Comment: True that's why I suggested use of naming like 1.1 or 3.3 and do some processing.

Answer (score 0):

For less confusion, I'd recommend assigning the controller to a variable:

```
var app = angular.module("myDiscuss", []);

app.controller("TabController", function() {
    var v = this;
    v.tab=0;
    v.selectTab = function(setTab) {
        v.tab= setTab;
    };
    v.isSelected = (function(checkTab){
        return v.tab === checkTab;
    });
});
```

This is because in function, `this` refers to the function, not the controller. By using a separate variable, you avoid the inconsistency.

Even the alias you're using, `TabController as tabs`, uses the same thing:

`$scope.tabs = this` internally.